# java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1

Tags: java, android, cordova

i get this when using phonegap`s Media.
the song does not play, instead i get error code 5

any ideas?

```
05-26 02:35:41.796 1153 8918 V PlayerDriver: HandleInformationalEvent: PVMFInfoErrorHandlingStart
05-26 02:35:41.796 1153 8918 V PlayerDriver: HandleInformationalEvent: type=26 UNHANDLED
05-26 02:35:41.796 8832 8837 W MediaPlayer: info/warning (1, 26)
05-26 02:35:41.796 8832 8832 I MediaPlayer: Info (1,26)
05-26 02:35:41.796 1153 8918 D : enter SharedLibraryLookup
05-26 02:35:41.796 1153 8918 D : enter GetFactoryAndMimeString
05-26 02:35:41.796 1153 8918 V PlayerDriver: CommandCompleted
05-26 02:35:41.796 1153 8918 V PlayerDriver: Completed command (7)PLAYER_PREPARE status=PVMFErrResource
05-26 02:35:41.796 1153 8918 E PlayerDriver: Command PLAYER_PREPARE completed with an error or info PVMFErrResource
05-26 02:35:41.796 8832 8836 E MediaPlayer: error (1, -17)
05-26 02:35:41.803 8832 8917 W System.err: java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
05-26 02:35:41.803 8832 8917 W System.err: at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
05-26 02:35:41.803 8832 8917 W System.err: at com.phonegap.AudioPlayer.startPlaying(AudioPlayer.java:209)
05-26 02:35:41.803 8832 8917 W System.err: at com.phonegap.AudioHandler.startPlayingAudio(AudioHandler.java:181)
05-26 02:35:41.803 8832 8917 W System.err: at com.phonegap.AudioHandler.execute(AudioHandler.java:64)
05-26 02:35:41.803 8832 8917 W System.err: at com.phonegap.api.PluginManager$1.run(PluginManager.java:86)
05-26 02:35:41.803 8832 8917 W System.err: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
05-26 02:35:41.803 1153 8918 V PVPlayer: check_for_live_streaming s=-2147483648, cancelled=0
05-26 02:35:41.803 1153 8918 V PlayerDriver: HandleInformationalEvent: PVMFInfoErrorHandlingComplete
05-26 02:35:41.803 1153 8918 W PlayerDriver: PVMFInfoErrorHandlingComplete
05-26 02:35:41.889 8832 8838 D cache : save chahe file for url http://127.0.0.1:43207/83f3430c-970d-4dfc-9aa2-159167b7c894
05-26 02:35:41.905 8832 8838 D cache : mDataBase.getCache() for url http://127.0.0.1:43207/83f3430c-970d-4dfc-9aa2-159167b7c894 len=70
05-26 02:35:42.007 8832 8838 D cache : save chahe file for url http://127.0.0.1:43207/83f3430c-970d-4dfc-9aa2-159167b7c894
05-26 02:35:42.038 1275 1279 D KeyguardViewMediator: setHidden false
05-26 02:35:42.069 1275 1861 D KeyguardViewMediator: setHidden false
05-26 02:35:42.717 1153 8890 V PlayerDriver: HandleInformationalEvent: PVMFInfoPositionStatus
```

Answer (score 2):

The description of `PVMFErrResource` is:

> Error due to general error in underlying resource

That's where you have to look: the *underlying resource* is most likely the file that you want to play. Maybe it's not accessible, maybe it's corrupt, maybe the type is not supported.

**Further Reading**

- [Android MediaPlayer Error codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857578/android-mediaplayer-error-codes) - a Q/A on SO

Answer (score 0):

Encountered a similar problem when with the audio file content is having issues with the android.
I am not sure why it happens.

I am assuming you are using mp3, try using a .ogg file instead.

Comment: no, if i convert it to ogg i get another error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139545/can-not-play-ogg-on-android

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same exception and was able to get it working by changing the location.
See [how-to-play-song-in-android-phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159117/how-to-play-song-in-android-phonegap) for the correct URL.