# can not play ogg on android

Tags: android, ogg

does somenone knows what this means?
the ogg is played with phonegap`s Meda, which uses MediaPlayer

```
05-26 15:41:50.007  1160  3631 E AudioFlinger: no more track names available
05-26 15:41:50.007  1160  3631 E AudioTrack: AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12
05-26 15:41:50.007  1160  3631 E AudioSink: Unable to create audio track
05-26 15:41:50.007  1160  3631 E VorbisPlayer: mAudioSink open failed
```

thanks!

edit:

```
new Media('/android_asset/www/sounds/0.mp3',
        function() {
        //alert("playAudio():Audio Success");
    },
        function(err, arg) {
            alert(err + ' ' + arg);
    }).play()
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html according to this you should be able to play ogg files . Please put some code that produce this exception

Comment: ok, but its just javascript, the java part is here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-android/blob/master/framework/src/com/phonegap/AudioPlayer.java

Comment: Me too. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  Were you able to solve it?

Comment: I'm confused. Did you name an ogg file `"0.mp3"`, or is it an mp3?

Answer (score 4):

I've had Ogg Vorbis music files that the internal Android player wouldn't play and I've found that removing all the Tags embedded in the file solved the problem. Variable bit rate and high bit rate doesn't seem to be the issue for me. The issue seems to be that the internal Android player chokes if the Ogg Vorbis file contains tags in certain formats. I haven't figured out precisely which tags in which formats are the problem. Some work. Some don't. I'll keep looking into the issue.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this post](http://www.anddev.org/multimedia-problems-f28/soundpool-crashing-with-could-not-create-track-t17028.html), you need to play ogg files with constant bitrate. Variable bitrate will cause SoundPool to crash.

There is a bug report about the same error message, but a different cause, here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13453

Comment: This is commonly cited as the solution. It didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this, but it is more like a workaround.
To me it seems like Android is not capable to play ogg-files which have a too high bitrate.
I re-encoded my ogg-files in audacity. In Audacity under 'file - export - options' you can configure the ogg-quality.  I have set the quality to 0 (I do not hear any difference).

For another song I had to re-encode my ogg to mp3 (48khz) and then back to ogg.