# Manifest permission needed to copy files to the Android device internal area?

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest, internal, basic4android

I would like to give the user the choice to copy files onto the Android device data directory as well as the external area.

Can you tell me what I need to add to the manifest that will allow my app to copy the files to the internal area?

I was planning on storing the files in /data/data/your.app.package.name/myFiles. In the code, File.DirInternal translates to that location.

If I use File.DirRootExternal, it goes to /mnt/sdcard which does not crash the app.

That's why I thought the manifest was causing the issue.

It crashes on this line if I use File.DirInternal:

```
mpTheMediaPlayer.Load(File.DirInternal, "114.mp3")
```

This is the code that's crashing:

```
' Http sub routines.
'-------------------
Sub JobDone(Job As String)

Select Job
    Case "Job1"

        If HttpUtils.IsSuccess(mp3Url) Then 
            Dim blnFolderMade As Boolean

            mp3 = HttpUtils.GetInputStream(mp3Url)

            timer1.Enabled = True

            Dim out As OutputStream
            out = File.OpenOutput(File.DirInternal,"114.mp3",False)
            File.Copy2(mp3, out)
            out.Close

            ProgressBarDownloading.Visible = False

            ToggleButtonPlayPause.Checked = True
            ToggleButtonPlayPause.Enabled = True
            blnCurrentPauseCheckedState = True
            blnCurrentPauseEnabledState = True

            mpTheMediaPlayer.Release
            mpTheMediaPlayer.Initialize2("")
            mpTheMediaPlayer.Load(File.DirInternal, "114.mp3")
            mpTheMediaPlayer.Play
        End If
End Select
End Sub
```

Here is the error from the logs:

```
Starting Job: Job1
** Service (httputilsservice) Create **
** Service (httputilsservice) Start **
main_jobdone (java line: 518)
java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
at anywheresoftware.b4a.objects.MediaPlayerWrapper.Load(MediaPlayerWrapper.java:79)
at quran.repeater.main._jobdone(main.java:518)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at anywheresoftware.b4a.BA.raiseEvent2(BA.java:113)
at anywheresoftware.b4a.BA.raiseEvent(BA.java:97)
at anywheresoftware.b4a.keywords.Common.CallSub4(Common.java:772)
at anywheresoftware.b4a.keywords.Common.CallSub2(Common.java:759)
at quran.repeater.httputilsservice._processnexttask(httputilsservice.java:180)
at quran.repeater.httputilsservice._response_streamfinish(httputilsservice.java:244)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at anywheresoftware.b4a.BA.raiseEvent2(BA.java:113)
at anywheresoftware.b4a.BA$1.run(BA.java:218)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at Android's [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) doc for details on saving to internal storage.

If you meant:

> /data/data/your.app.package.name/myFiles

Then you don't need extra permissions. That's just regular writing to internal storage

If you meant external storage (which it sure doesn't look like) then you need

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If you truly meant

> /data/myApp/myFiles

Then the answer is that you can't without being rooted. You don't have permissions to write to the /data folder.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to do the copy to /data/data/your.app.package.name/myFiles but I get a "prepare failed" error. I'm trying to copy a file that I use the media player to play. Also the device I'm using is rooted but I'm not sure if the user's device will be rooted.

Comment: Update your original post with your code and the exception with stack trace, and I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated the post with the code and logs.

Comment: Seems like a problem with MediaPlayer and not storage. See these [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761305/android-mediaplayer-throwing-prepare-failed-status-0x1-on-2-1-works-on-2-2) [posts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138328/java-io-ioexception-prepare-failed-status-0x1).

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Looks like I need to stick with only File.DirRootExternal as the location to put the files as it seems it is the only one the mp3 file will play from so it does look like media player does not like the File.DirInternal location.

Answer (score 2):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Its the same permission to write both on internal storage or SD card.

Comment: Thanks for the very fast reply. I'll give it a try in a while.

Comment: His question is about Internal storage. Your permission for External storage

Comment: He meant default storage space which comes with the phone(8GB/16GB/32GB), not the SD card.

Comment: It allows my to copy files to mnt/sdcard but not data/myApp/myFiles. Is there another line of information that needs to go into the manifest file?

Comment: You should try this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#AccessingExtFiles